# what is the probability that the next random number will equal current one?

Tags: excel, vba, random

if i do this in a worksheet:

```
=RAND()
```

i also specified that i want only 2 decimal places

and for example let's say that `rand() = 0.07`

what is the probability that when i call this function again i will get `0.07` ??

i know that ideally if we assume 100% randomness, the answer would be `1/ (10 * 10)` because there are only 100 possible combinations, but what would it be according to the way excel generates a random number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random number generator in Excel is pretty good these days.  You're going to get really close to it being a 1 in 100 chance.  1 in 101 if you allow 0.0 and 1.0.

Article about the number generator:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828795

Answer (score 1):

If the random function is uniform, then the probability is 1/100.   That's usually
what non-mathematicians expect when they specify "random".